# Unable to render ASPxGridView after upgrading from DevEx 11.2 to DevEx 18.1

Tags: .net, devexpress

I have upgraded my project's DevExpress from V11.2 to V18.1. Everything worked fine. But on few pages, I am not able to view the grid that is rendered using ASPxGridView tag.
I have wrapped this tag in my own class and is using that class throughout the project.
I am not getting any errors/warnings. It's just that the grid is not loading on the page.

I have been stuck in it for long, if anybody could help me with it. Thanks.

Comment: Is the GridView not showing up in browser view? Check browser console and references to make sure there are no errors.

Comment: Have you used the project update tool provided by DevExpress to make the update process smooth..